# Remove pin to close switch

Tags: switches

I'm looking for a small fairly rugged normally open switch that closes when a "pin" is removed. It needs to take about 12V It needs to be passive and not require power. Is there such a component?

Basically, I want to be able to pull *out* a pin or a small plug to turn a device on.

I can think of a mechanical solution, a plastic pin that blocks the current flow, once removed the contacts would press together. But, for my application (a drone) I don't think I can build something rugged enough.

So is there a type of store-bought component that will do this?

Comment: sure.  take a clothes pin, the old wooden type, glue some copper pads to the ends, for contacts.  Then add wire to each contact.  insert some insulator like a piece of hard plastic for the "Pin."  There you have it.  I hope this isn't for some kind of bomb.  No, of course not in this day & age.

Comment: Take a look [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=interlock+switch&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=961&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIoZPMuenLAhXGbSYKHWFJCocQ7AkIYg&dpr=1)

Comment: Any pin-activated switch which is SPDT will do what you want. You use the common and the NC contacts.

Comment: These things often go as *remove before flight switch [or pin]*.  It's also possible to rig a switch like that out of a DC barrel jack.

Answer (score 2):

3.5mm Audio Jack with switch?
DC Barrel Jack (2.1mm / 2.5mm) with internal switch lip?
About any round connector meant for low power multi-media will have variants with a switch inside.