# Switch or gate that activates when not grounded

Tags: arduino, switches, audio

I have a audio jack with a build in switch that when an nothing is plunged in the switch lead is grounded but when you plug something in its no longer grounded. I want to use this audio jack as a power switch so when you plug in something an arduino gets power and turns on.

I am not running power through the jacks, I am using them for audio in my project. I am making a small box with no visible switches that when you plug in some ear phones it turns on and plays music. I just need some kind of switch or relay that will turn on the device when the switch leg if of the audio jack is no longer connected to ground.

[image]

I am not sure how to make this circuit, maybe there is some kind of transistor or relay that works this way but i just don't know about it.

Please help.

Comment: Don't you think a photo would be a good idea?

Comment: A photo wont really help, the audio jack as three legs, a positive, negative and switch. The switch leg is connected to ground when nothing is plugged in but when something is plugged in it breaks the ground connection.

Comment: A photo will help. There are many types of audio jack, mono, stereo, with multiple contact arrangements. Audio does not use "positive and negative" - it uses signal and ground.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [Remove pin to close switch](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225581/remove-pin-to-close-switch) and [What to do with third contact in DC barrel plug with only two input contacts?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90529/7036)

Comment: There are lots of audio jacks with different switching arrangements, so in order for us not have to waste a lot of time helping you out, you could help us out by posting a part number,  a photo, or a schematic.

Comment: [Photo of jacks](http://www.inaflashgraphics.com/uploads/s-l1600.jpg)
These are the audio jacks i am using, this photo is from the ebay listing.

Comment: The switch contact doesn't seem to be inherently grounded, it's floating unless you intentionally ground it.

Comment: @EMFields is correct re "floating contact: comment - which is why I said " ...IF one side of the audio is grounded (as your comments suggest)..."  in my answer. If audio path does not have one side grounded then what I suggested works in principle but needs some idea of how the jack is used. You may know that, we don't. Lay on ...

Answer (score 2):

**IF** one side of the audio is grounded (as your comments suggest)
**then** adding an eg 10k resistor from the pin which gets isolated to V+ will produce a DC signal on plug insertion. If desired an LED across the ground-isolated contact would light when the plug was inserted. (With 10k and 5V and eg red LED level is low but usable.

If the resultant standby current is too high (eg 1/2 mA at 5V) the you can use eg 1M (5 uA) or 10M (0.5 uA) at 5V with suitable following logic. An eg xx74x14 Schmitt trigger inverter will wok with 10M and leave you 5 of the 6 gates spare for other use. (Flash an LED when on or whatever).The higher value resistors make the simple LED + resistor indicator impractical but adding a package of Schmitt inverters can add an LED driver + much bonus capability.

---

**Two examples of possible methods.**

The diagram at left can be used if one audio lead is grounded.
If headphone or internal circuit is DC coupled the capacitors C2 & C3 at right may be needed.
As shown the LED is on with plug OUT but by moving the LED to across the switch the opposite occurs. Quiescent current drain may be higher than desired if LED  is to be driven. R2 may be increased - see text above.

The right hand version allows the audio path to have neither leg grounded.
Resistors set load on audio, audio balaance, DC point of audio leg. C2, C3 may be needed if input or output not AC coupled.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWXSvN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

**___________________**

**GETTING BETTER EASIER FASTER ANSWERS**

I added the image and your relevant comments and edited YOUR questionvery slightly.

**Now:**

1. Add the ebay link
2. Stop arguing :-)
3. Answer good technical questions politely rather than resisting them - if you knew what was wanted and/or relevant you would not need to ask the question.  If you maximise information and answer technical questions and describe what you are trying to do and known constraints then you **WILL** get a good solution here if the question is on topic (and maybe also if its not).

But, hiding photos, hiding source and data references, hiding real use and more (all of which you are effectively doing ) leads to a long slow misunderstood teeth pulling approach.

Comment: An upvote and, as always, a pleasure to read you.  :)

Comment: @EMFields Flattery will get you somewhere :-)

Comment: I"m not about that, but I do like kindness, when warranted.

Comment: @EMFields Yes. The flattery comment was a joke, of sorts. Sincere flattery always welcome :-). Kindness seems warranted often enough. Over the years (since long before Stack Exchange days) I've tried to take note of what Olin has to say about dealing with people, what his aims are and how effective and how reasonable the approach is. He and I have many major aims in common when it comes to trying to get the best from people BUT our approaches are "somewhat different" and he seems neither to see any merit in my approach or to acknowledge that I care about improving people's abilities. ...

Comment: ... [Whether the above "seems" reflects reality is not something I know or that he's going to tell me :-).] | So eg in this case, I've ended with some fairly robust (and, hopefully, useful) input aimed at the O BUT preceded it by as much practical advice as seems reasonable at this stage. Best case he picks up the ball and runs with it. Worst case - you can't win them all. Lately a number of OP's have done brilliantly after very shaky starts. All good fun ... .  :-)

Comment: With regard to Olin:  I've only been here a year or so, so I'm still a newbie, but my view is that he seems to want to rule by  intimidation, considers disagreement with his edicts to be blasphemous, and is willing to do whatever's necessary - right or wrong - to wear the catbird crown.

Comment: @EMFields It takes a while to appeciate (either way) most people's attributes and Olin is no exception. He can be extremely 'giving', happy to spend much time and effort on assisting people, and 'in another time line' freely donates the products of his expertise so that others can benefit from them.  These various 'good points' do not excuse anything inexcusable BUT provide a broader context in which to see what a person is about.He and I both want people to help themselves and to achieve their aims. We have different ways of attempting to achieve it :-). He considers that if people will ...

Comment: ... not meet a certain standard and/or show no signs of helping themselves or or appreciating what is being done for them then it would be better if the leave. I agree that if people persist in not trying or working at things then there comes a point where it's not worth attempting to help. Where the point is is moot - and in too many cases, misunderstandings occur early on that can be easily enough remedied.  Much more  could can be written ...

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to use an audio jack for power - especially if power is coming from an audio plug - because it's almost impossible to keep from shorting the supply as the plug is being inserted into the jack.

Use, instead, one of the many barrel jacks available.

Comment: I am not running power through the jacks, i am using them for audio in my project. I am making a small box with no viable switches that when you plug in some ear phones it turns on and plays music. I just need some kind of switch or relay that will turn on the device when the switch leg if of the audio jack is no longer connected to ground.

Comment: That's a completely different scenario from the one you asked for help with, and if all you want to do is to plug into audio from the Arduino, all you need to do is connect the audio signal from the Arduino to the tip contact of the jack, the Arduino's ground to the sleeve contact, and let the switch contact float.